# Magento 2 : Get Customer ID Based on Nickname of Review

Tags: magento2, customer, review

I want to get `customer_id` from a customer that has written a review.

In `review_details` there is a row for that, and there is function `getNickname()`.

[image]

How can I get `customer_id` in my module? What do I need to create in order to get that piece of information?

Answer (score 0):

As the `nick_name` is not a unique field in the `review_detail` table, you could use the combination of two fields `review_id` or any other field which you find appropriate and `nick_name` to filter the collection.